# How to add new column to DataTable with auto index of row (C#)

Tags: c#

I have a Datatable, and I need to add "id" or "index" column with auto value.
like a identity column in sql.

I have a function that return me the start index: GetID();
I need that the value of this column in the first row will be the value that GetID() return, the value in the second row will be GetID() + 1.... GetID() + 2 ...

I need to do this **without loops** .
I thought to use "Expression" when I create new column, but I dont know how to do this.

Comment: Can't the identifier be queried from the data source when populating the `DataTable`?  Why can't you use loops?  Your requirements are unclear and I don't see what attempt you've made or how that attempt didn't succeed.

Comment: The table is very very big. I can not use loops, and i can not change the proce procedures

Comment: You can use loops (they're quite good at iterating over elements in a set and applying an operation to each element), you simply choose not to.  Which is a pretty arbitrary restriction.  Also, what is the actual purpose of this identifier that isn't really an identifier?  Any time the data is re-fetched from the data source it's going to have a potentially different identifier.  That seems like it would introduce more problems than it solves...

Comment: I can't see why you can't use loops. Are they banned or something? Otherwise I'd say this is the kind of restriction applied in interview or homework questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AutoIncrement` property of DataTable column:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
var col = dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof (long));
col.AutoIncrement = true;
col.AutoIncrementSeed = GetID();
col.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
```

But it will work only for rows being added to your DataTable **after** adding this column.

If you adding this identity column to the DataTable with existed rows - this will not update existed rows, so in this case you're still need loop over your existed rows and update them manually.